# Bitcoin для программиста. Прием, обмен, передача.

Tags: сервисы

Как организовать прием и проверку поступления программно, без стороннего сервиса?
Куда копать, что читать?

Answer (score 1):

[API для разных языков, там же ссылка на список функций](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC))